# Defining a recursive type hint in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's say I have a function that accepts a `Garthok`, an `Iterable[Garthok]`, an `Iterable[Iterable[Garthok]]`, etc.

```
def narfle_the_garthoks(arg):
  if isinstance(arg, Iterable):
    for value in arg:
       narfle_the_garthoks(arg)
  else:
    arg.narfle()
```

Is there any way to specify a type hint for arg that indicates that it accepts any level of `Iterable`s of `Garthok`s? I suspect not, but thought I'd check if I'm missing something.

As a workaround, I'm just specifying a few levels deep, and then ending with `Iterable[Any]`.

```
Union[Garthok,
    Iterable[Union[Garthok,
        Iterable[Union[Garthok, 
            Iterable[Union[Garthok, Iterable[Any]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive type annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638973/recursive-type-annotations)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can specify recursive types in the typing language by using [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) and [forward reference strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references),

```
Garthoks = Union[Garthok, Iterable['Garthoks']]
```

Note that recursive types are not yet supported by mypy. [But it will likely be added eventually.](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731)

---

Update 2020/9/14: [Microsoft announces support for recursive types in Pyright/Pylance.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/pylance-introduces-five-new-features-that-enable-type-magic-for-python-developers/)

---

> Some types of forward references are handled by [PEP0563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). You can use them starting from Python 3.7 by doing `from __future__ import annotations` – Konstantin

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks! It doesn't seem to be supported by IDEA/PyCharm either.

Comment: @JesusFreke There are a few other Python type checkers that I've heard of. Besides mypy and pycharm, there's also [Facebook's Pyre](https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check) and [Google's pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype)

Comment: Isn't there also just a way to define your own custom type annotation like those in the `typing` library? I was sure the answer was yes, but I can't find how. Is it just a class which declares that all (`Iterable`s of )*`Garthok`s are its subclasses or something?

Comment: @DanielH classes are types. You can also use `TypeVars` and subclass `Generic` for that `[]` syntax.

Comment: @DanielH Yeah, I didn't see anything like that. But as a bonus, while perusing the typing documentation just now, I discovered the unrelated `@typing.overload` decorator, which I needed for something else :D

Comment: You can generate test strategies for recursive types in the "hypothesis" module as follows https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.deferred

Comment: Some types of forward references are handled by PEP0563. You can use them starting from Python 3.7 by doing `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible to write `NestedList = list[str | "NestedList"]` instead of `NestedList = list[Union[str, "NestedList"]]` since it raises `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'str'`.

Comment: @d-k-bo I used `from typing import Type; NestedStr = list[str | Type["NestedStr"]]` to solve this but when I try to do this: 
`def get_first(x: str | NestedStr) -> str: \
    if isinstance(x, str): return x  \
    return get_first(x[0])`
I got an error saying `Argument of type "str | NestedStr" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "str | NestedStr" in function "get_first"`

Answer (score -1):

MyPy comes with this limitation, it does not support cyclic reference yet, but I found a way to work it round using TypeVars like so:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, TypeAlias, Iterable, Union

T = TypeVar('T')
_Garthoks: TypeAlias = Union[T, Iterable[T]]
Garthoks: TypeAlias = _Garthoks[_Garthoks[_Garthoks[_Garthoks]]]
# you can nest it as deep as you need...
```

Currently, I find it to be the best solution util MyPy support this feature.

I hope it solves your problem.