# Python annotation's type for nested list with undefined nested list depth

Tags: python, annotations, typing

Type of `[[1, 2, 3], 3, [2, 4], 5]` is `list[list[int] | int]`. But what type nested list would have if it has undefined depth e.g. `[[[1, 2]], 2, [1, [3, [3]]]], 3, [2, [2]]]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining a recursive type hint in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845024/defining-a-recursive-type-hint-in-python)

Comment: @VladimirFokow No. In my opinion that question does not provide minimal and reproducible example. Also those answers confusing. One answer is `Union[TypeVar('T'), Iterable[TypeVar('T')]]` but in accepted answer another code given `Union[_, Iterable['_']]`. Additionally accepted answer says that "Some types of forward references are handled by PEP0563" without any examples. One comment provide an example `list[Union[str, "NestedList"]]` but it makes it even more confusing because `NestedList` was not defined in answer.  And once again the question itself is not clear for me.

Comment: The answer that uses `TypeVar('T')` says it is just a **workaround** for previous versions of MyPy - so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: The comment that provides: `NestedList = list[Union[str, "NestedList"]]` wasn't meant to answer the question, but rather to illustrate a point that `NestedList = list[str | "NestedList"]` [was not supported](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/7904#issuecomment-1148165913). However, that comment gives an answer to this question exactly.

Comment: @VladimirFokow So can I define `NestedList = list[Union[str, "NestedList"]]` and use it in function definition like `def f(l: NestedList) -> int: ...` or do I need to use something like `Recursive: TypeAlias = str | list["Recursive"]` with  `def f(l: Recursive) -> int: ...` instead?

Comment: your `Recursive` can be a `str`, but your `NestedList` cannot. Choose the one which suits your needs.

Comment: As far as I understand, the `: TypeAlias` part is not mandatory. Just without it mypy complained to me. So I would use it.

Comment: It looks for like `NestedList` can be `str` because it is `union` of `str` and `NestedList`. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It is a **list** that can contain either a NestedList or a string ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a recursive type alias:

```py
T: TypeAlias = list[Union[int, 'T']]
```

Comment: giving the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'str'`

Comment: @illuminato, sorry, my bad. Corrected now

Comment: Could you please explain what `'T'` means?  What is the difference between your code and `list[Union[int, TypeVar("T")]]`?

Comment: @illuminato, Unfortunately, I don't understand in full detail. I think `'T'` is a [`forward reference`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0613/#forward-references). If you `print(T)`, you see `list[typing.Union[int, ForwardRef('T')]]`. However, currently `mypy` complains (by default): "Cannot resolve name "T" (possible cyclic definition)mypy(error)". 3 days ago [Support recursive types #731](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731) issue was closed, saying that now we can set a flag `-enable-recursive-aliases`.