# What type hints should be used for recursively nested objects in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, types

For instance, what is a good syntax for a type like that:

```py
list[int | list[int | ...]]
```

Basically, for a `list` of `int`s that could be of any (strictly positive) dimension.

Comment: Maybe something like that would make sense: `T_ = Grid[Node | T_]`... But this does not seem to be a proper syntax.

Comment: Recursive types are not yet officially supported, but see https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13297.

Comment: The *syntax* is fine; it's the semantics that fall apart. (Python would accept `T_ = Grid[Node | 'T_']`--a standard forward reference--but `mypy` will fail to resolve the cycle.)

Comment: @chepner I think `pyright` supports recursive definitions

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845024/defining-a-recursive-type-hint-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution, by following the logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53845083/5561649) (as suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga), and using a forward reference.

The type (`T`) for an n-dimensional `list` of `int`s could be noted as:

```py
import typing
T = list[typing.Union[int, 'T']]
```

---

N.B.: whereas `typing.Union(T1, T2)` can also be written as `T1 | T2`, it doesn't work in the context of this answer (as of Python 3.9):

```py
>>> T = list[int | 'T']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'str'
```