# typing recursive function with nested type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance

background: solving some algorithm problem

### Problem

I'm trying to use a recursive function with nested type in VSCode, and it keep throwing error to me. I reduced it to this

```py
from typing import Type

NestedStr = list[str | Type["NestedStr"]]


def get_first(x: str | NestedStr) -> str:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    return get_first(x[0]) # Argument of type "str | NestedStr" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "str | NestedStr" in function "get_first"


assert get_first(["a", "b"]) == "a" # No error thrown here
assert get_first([["a", "b"]]) == "a" # Argument of type "list[list[str]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "str | NestedStr" in function "get_first"
```

Obviously, when `x` is not an `str` it should be a `NestedStr` hence it can be an infinite nested list but pylance seems not knowing it.
The code can run perfectly but the error is annoying. Is there anyway to suppress it (except "type: ignore")?

### Related

- [PEP483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/)
- [Defining a recursive type hint in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845024/defining-a-recursive-type-hint-in-python/53845083#comment132174059_53845083)

### Appendices

#### Full Error Messages

- on recursive call `get_first(x[0])`

```
Argument of type "str | NestedStr" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "str | NestedStr" in function "get_first"
  Type "str | NestedStr" cannot be assigned to type "str | NestedStr"
    Type "NestedStr" cannot be assigned to type "str | NestedStr"
      "Type[type]" is incompatible with "Type[str]"
      "Type[type]" is incompatible with "NestedStr" Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues
```

- on call with `list[list[str]]`

```
Argument of type "list[list[str]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "str | NestedStr" in function "get_first"
  Type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to type "str | NestedStr"
    "list[str]" is incompatible with "str"
    Type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to type "NestedStr" Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Comment: why are you using `Type['NestedList']`?

Comment: I tried running the same locally, and it doesn't throw any error. What version of python are you running?

Comment: @Noblyat pylance v2022.12.20. The Python runs the entire code correctly just pylance (of VSCode) raises this error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please check the first line : "background: solving some algorithm problem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my view this `NestedStr = list[str | Type["NestedStr"]]` has to be changed to that `NestedStr = list[str | "NestedStr"]`, as it is either a string or a concrete instance of NestedStr, but not the plain type. I haven't checked with pylance, but mypy accepts that and doesn't raise any issue.

Comment: `NestedStr = list[str | "NestedStr"]` works! Idk why when I tried this first it reported some error, and then I switched to `NestedStr = list[str | Type["NestedStr"]]`

Answer (score 0):

As in `Pylance v2023.3.20`
@Simon Hawe's answer throws an error `"NestedStr" is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVariable)`

The current solution is like this:

```py
from typing import Union

NestedStr = list[Union[str, "NestedStr"]]


def get_first(x: str | NestedStr) -> str:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    return get_first(x[0])
    # or the shorter and working version in next line:
    # return x if isinstance(x, str) else get_first(x[0])


assert get_first([["a", "b"]]) == "a"
```