# Type hints for variably-nested Dict in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Since I'm working a lot with type hints in Python I came across the scenario that a recursive function accepts `dict`, with `str` as keys and `int` or `dict` as value (`Dict[str, Union[int, Dict[...]]`). The problem at this point is that the possible `dict`-value has also `str` as keys and `int` or `dict` as value (`Dict[str, Union[int, Dict[Dict[str, Union[int, Dict[...]]]]`).

However, I don't know which depth the passed dictionary has. Is there any possibility to visualize this repetitive pattern with type hints?

Comment: See also [How can I type-hint a nested object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498869/how-can-i-type-hint-a-nested-object-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a generic type that is not a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363364/how-to-define-a-generic-type-that-is-not-a-class)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. What I mean is that my dict could had a depth from 0 to infinite. So basically what I want is a type hint that could insert itself at some point (in my example at `...`, because then the whole hint would repeat itself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yearned-for syntax is something like:

```
RecursiveDict = Dict[str, Union['RecursiveDict', int]]
```

As of now, MyPy (and most other Python type-checkers) don't support this syntax — the MyPy [bug report](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731) asking for support for recursive types has been open for 6 years. However, some alternative type-checkers [have recently](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/pylance-introduces-five-new-features-that-enable-type-magic-for-python-developers/) introduced support for recursive annotations. So, it's a bit of a mixed bag.

See also:

- [Defining a recursive type hint in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845024/defining-a-recursive-type-hint-in-python)
- [Recursive type annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638973/recursive-type-annotations)

Comment: As per https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13297 it is supported now.

Comment: @ניר I still can't get the code from the answer working.